# 13.10: Ubuntu One has no contextual menu item or icons on folders

Tags: ubuntu-one, 13.10, context-menu

Since installing 13.10 on my computer, my folders syncing with Ubuntu One do not have any icons on them (tick, arrows etc) to signify the state of the folder.

Also, upon right-clicking, there is no Ubuntu One menu either.

Is this a bug? Or is there a way I can fix it?

[image: No sync icons in 13.10 for Ubuntu One]

Comment: I found this behavior under Nautilus and Nemo

Comment: @TFXTFX - you have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts, click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your other accounts are merged.  Once done, you'll be able to edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Comment: Done. I have the client installed but I'm still not getting any notifications on my folder icons or any Ubuntu One contextual menu upon right clicking a file/folder.

Comment: It is not a bug, and you can't install it, no. As my answer said, it was removed from the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it has been [removed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1196684).

Some people complain in this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1232053), which also gives a workaround by installing the version from Raring (13.04). If you are using amd64 (64bit):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/135421143/ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/135422714/libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

For i386 (32bit):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/135421153/ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/135423443/libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.de
rm ubuntuone-client-gnome_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.de
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. The `ubuntuone-client-gnome` package was removed from the distribution.